# how to get Id of last added row when using entity framework with unit of work pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

how to get Id of last added row when using entity framework with unit of work pattern??
I know after SaveChanges() the auto incremented column gets autometically updated you can get it as:-

```
Comment comment=new comment();
    comment.username="sachin";
    db.saveChanges();
var id= comment.commentId;
```

(Easy Solution)  but how to do the same when using unit of work??And please don't say why u need unit of work DbContext is already unit of work.
Action in Controller

```
public ActionResult Savecomment(string comment)
                    {
                        var user = (from a in _registrationService.GetAllRegistrations() where a.Email == Convert.ToString(Session["Email"]) select a).FirstOrDefault();

                        var userid = Convert.ToInt32(user.UserId);
                        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                            Comment cmt = new Comment();
                            cmt.CommentId = cmt.CommentId;
                            cmt.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
                            cmt.PostId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["pid"]);
                            cmt.UserId = userid;
                            cmt.Body = comment;
                            _commentService.CreateComment(cmt);

                            var id=cmt.CommentId;//I need this
                            var res = _commentService.GetCommentById(id);
                            return Json(res,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");


                    }
```

Service Method

```
public Comment CreateComment(Comment CommentEntity)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                var Comment = new Comment
                {
                    CommentId=CommentEntity.CommentId,
                    Body = CommentEntity.Body,
                    UserId = CommentEntity.UserId,
                    DateTime = CommentEntity.DateTime,
                    PostId=CommentEntity.PostId,

                };
                _unitOfWork.CommentRepository.Insert(Comment);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
               scope.Complete();
                return Comment;
            }
        }
```

unit of work:-

```
public Repository<Comment> CommentRepository
            {
                get
                {
                    if (this._CommentRepository == null)
                        this._CommentRepository = new Repository<Comment>(_context);
                    return _CommentRepository;
                }
            }

     public void Save()
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {

                    var outputLines = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        outputLines.Add(string.Format("{0}: Entity of type \"{1}\" in state \"{2}\" has the following validation errors:", DateTime.Now, eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            outputLines.Add(string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
                        }
                    }
                    //System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\errors.txt", outputLines);

                    throw e;
                }

            }
```

Comment: On your `CommentRepository` you need to create a method that returns the last inserted comment

Comment: Why don't you just insert the `CommentEntity` object? It'll have the Id value afterwards. Or else read the value from the returned comment which you discard in your current code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method on your `CommentRepository` that returns the last inserted comment:

```
public class CommentRepository: ICommentRepository //Only if you have the interface
{   
    internal DbContext _context;
    internal DbSet<Comment> dbSet;

    public CommentRepository(DbContext context)//I think you have something like this.
    {
        _context = context;
        dbSet = context.Set<Comment>();
    }

    (...)
    public int ReturnLast()
    {
        //Use your context or DbSet here to return the data.
        //You are using .Last() but I'm not sure if that gets what you want.
        var lastComment = dbSet.ToList().Last();
        return lastComment.Id;
    }
}
```

Then when you are using your UnitOfWork just access it:

```
var comment = _uow.CommentRepository.ReturnLast();
```

I don't know how your repository is built, so I'm just guessing here. You should not use UnitOfWork inside of the repository.

Comment: public int ReturnLast()
    {   var lastcomment=_unitOfWork.CommentRepository.getAllComments().last();     var lastcommentId=lastcomment.CommentId;
        return lastcommentId;
    }

Comment: Is it? You should be using the `context` and `DbSet` and not the `UnitOfWork`. And yeah, this method is returning a `Comment`, but if you want `Id` only that's the way. I'll update the answer then.

Comment: I generally follow the below Architecture:-
Bussiness Entity-->Bussiness Services-->DAL-->Generic Repository-->Unit of Work-->WebApp(MVC)
where Generic Repository is for basic CRUD.
      Business Services is where all other methods are defined.I call the Generic Repository via UOW here to define other methods than CRUD.
      I dont use DbContext directly in Services.Otherwise what will be the advantages of UOW.

Comment: I follow the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application). So what I understood from there is that you should use you UOW in the WebApp. The UOW repositories are communicating with the DbContext.